# How to find and replace text within ".." using bash script

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace this line `#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1","host2"]` with `discovery.seed_hosts: ["${extraNode1}","${extraNode2}","${masterIP}"]`. Need to remove the `#` and replace the host1 and host2 as per the given argument also need to add another value (3rd value) into the array as well.

`sudo sed -i "/#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1","host2"]/s/#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1","host2"]/discovery.seed_hosts: ["${extraNode1}","${extraNode2}","${masterIP}"]/" check.yml`

I tried the above command to do this but it is giving error because of the `["host1","host2"]` in the command.

`sed: -e expression #1, char 49: Invalid range end`  - Error received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `s` (substitute) command, and escape `.`, in addition to `[`. Like this:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#\(discovery\.seed_hosts: \["\)host1","host2"]/\1${extraNode1}","${extraNode2}","${masterIP}"]/' check.yml
```

If you don't scape the `.`, the `sed` command will match any character where the `.` is, like `#discovery7seed_hosts: ["host1","host2"]`.

The `sed` command is pretty straight forward. I just added parentheses around the part of the match that I wanted to reuse in the substitution which creates a group. The `\1` is replace with "group 1", the contents of what's in between the parentheses, which must be escaped too.

EDIT: The `"`, double quotes, don't need to be escaped because the `sed` command is in single quotes: `'s/.../.../'`. Also, the `]`, closing square bracket, doesn't need to be escaped as long as its corresponding `[`, opening square bracket, has been escaped. Finally, both parentheses `(` and `)` need to be escaped to create the group. (END OF EDIT)

Test:

```
$ cat check.yml 
This is a test
Another line
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1","host2"]
#discovery7seed_hosts: ["host1","host2"]

OK. Good bye?
$ sed 's/#\(discovery\.seed_hosts: \["\)host1","host2"]/\1${extraNode1}","${extraNode2}","${masterIP}"]/' check.yml 
This is a test
Another line
discovery.seed_hosts: ["${extraNode1}","${extraNode2}","${masterIP}"]
#discovery7seed_hosts: ["host1","host2"]

OK. Good bye?

$
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have doubt why you dont escape the ] after the host2\"] - here you are escaping " but not the ] dont we need to put like this  
\[\"\)host1\",\"host2\"\]

Comment: \"host2\"]/\1${extraNode1}", here also we have to escape the " no ??
 
\"host2\"]/\1${extraNode1}\"

Comment: @AthavanT, you only have to scape the opening `[` not the closing. The parser takes care of it. As for the `"`, double quotes, they don't need to be escaped in this case because the `sed` command is in single quotes: `'s/.../.../'`. I'll correct that in the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape `[`s and `"`s with backslashes as:

```
sudo sed -i "/#discovery.seed_hosts: \[\"host1\",\"host2\"]/s/#discovery.seed_hosts: \[\"host1\",\"host2\"]/discovery.seed_hosts: [\""${extraNode1}\"",\""${extraNode2}\"",\""${masterIP}\""]/" check.yml
```